# WPF При изменении разрешения экрана возникает искажение в виде ступеньки

Tags: c#, wpf

Сделал форму WPF. Все выровнял. Однако при просмотре программы на мониторе с более высоким разрешением возникают искажения в виде "ступеньки". Как от них избавиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ckMarker" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Маркеры объектов" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckMarker_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckZone" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Зоны оповещения" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckZone_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckDangerTerritory" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="Опасные объекты" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckDangerTerritory_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckDangerZone" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Content="Зоны поражения" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckDangerZone_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckHidrography" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Content="Гидрография" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckHidrography_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckFire" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Content="Пожары" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckFire_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckVideo" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Видеонаблюдение" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckVideo_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckMobile" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Мобильные объекты" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckMobile_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckSpecial" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="Спецобъекты" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckSpecial_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckControl" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Content="Пункты управления" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckControl_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckTOR" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Content="Устройства мониторинга" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckTOR_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckSocial" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Content="Социальные объекты" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ckSocial_Click"/>
```

Comment: Код от `Grid` покажите. И проверьте DPI монитора где отображаются ступеньками.

Comment: <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой эффект дает установка свойства `Padding`, уберите его

> Свойство `Padding` увеличивает эффективный размер дочернего элемента на заданное значение

В данном случае вам просто подойдет установка нужного `Margin`, например `Margin="5,5,0,5"`

В более сложных случаях задайте контент чекбоксу явно:

```
<CheckBox>
    <TextBlock Margin="0,5">Зоны оповещения</TextBlock>
</CheckBox>
```